# FCM Service gets killed after i swipe my app from multi task tray

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service, android-notifications

I have an app that triggers incoming calls by FCM data message(priority: high, no notification payload).
When the app is in the foreground or background, the app receives calls.
For the above case, the notification(Incoming Call) is received when in Locked Screen.

But for some reason, when the app is closed or swiped from the multi-task tray, calls are no more received. I think that the service is killed. what can I do?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
```

Firebase Messaging class manifest declaration

```
<service
        android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**Workflow**
When FCM notification is received, a background service is started, then the service changes itself to the foreground service with "Incoming call" notification. I'm also using full-screen intent. The below class is what I use as Service

```
class IncomingCallNotificationService : Service() {

private val TAG = IncomingCallNotificationService::class.java.simpleName
var isRunning = false
private lateinit var soundUri: Uri

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + applicationContext.packageName + "/" + R.raw.incoming)
    val videoCallDetails: VideoNotification?= intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.VIDEO_CALL_DETAILS)
    val notificationId = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0)
    val action = intent.action
    if (action != null) {
        when(action){
            ACTION_INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION -> { handleIncomingCall(videoCallDetails!!, notificationId) }
            ACTION_ACCEPT -> {
                endForeground()
                val intent = Intent(this, VideoActivity::class.java)
                intent.action = ACTION_INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION
                intent.putExtra(Constants.ROOM_CODE, videoCallDetails?.roomCode)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.ROOM_NAME, videoCallDetails?.roomName)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN, videoCallDetails?.accessToken)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.CALLER_NAME, videoCallDetails?.userName)
                intent.putExtra(
                    Constants.CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY,
                    Constants.INCOMING_CALL_SCREEN
                )
                intent.putExtra(Constants.CALL_TYPE, Constants.VIDEO_CALL)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.NOTIFCATION_ID, notificationId)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                intent.action = ACTION_ACCEPT
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            ACTION_REJECT -> {
                endForeground()
                val it = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)
                applicationContext.sendBroadcast(it)
            }
        }
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY
}


override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return null
}

private fun createNotification(
    videoCallDetails: VideoNotification,
    notificationId: Int,
    channelImportance: Int
): Notification? {
    val intent = Intent(this, VideoActivity::class.java)
    intent.action = ACTION_INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ROOM_CODE, videoCallDetails.roomCode)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ROOM_NAME, videoCallDetails.roomName)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN, videoCallDetails.accessToken)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.CALLER_NAME, videoCallDetails.userName)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY, Constants.INCOMING_CALL_SCREEN)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.CALL_TYPE, Constants.VIDEO_CALL)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL, true)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.NOTIFCATION_ID, notificationId)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        notificationId,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    /*
     * Pass the notification id and call sid to use as an identifier to cancel the
     * notification later
     */
    val extras = Bundle()
    extras.putString(Constants.ROOM_CODE, videoCallDetails.roomCode)
    extras.putString(Constants.ROOM_NAME, videoCallDetails.roomName)
    extras.putString(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN, videoCallDetails.accessToken)
    extras.putString(Constants.CALLER_NAME, videoCallDetails.userName)
    extras.putString(Constants.CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY, Constants.INCOMING_CALL_SCREEN)
    extras.putString(Constants.CALL_TYPE, Constants.VIDEO_CALL)

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        buildNotification(
            videoCallDetails.userName + " is calling.",
            pendingIntent,
            extras,
            videoCallDetails,
            notificationId,
            createChannel(channelImportance)!!
        )
    } else {
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call_end_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL_TEXT)
            .setContentText(videoCallDetails.userName + " is calling.")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setExtras(extras)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setTimeoutAfter(MomsezeApplication.notificationTimeOut)
            .setGroup("test_app_notification")
            .setColor(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
            .setSound(soundUri)
        val notification = builder.build()
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT
        return notification
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun buildNotification(
    text: String, pendingIntent: PendingIntent, extras: Bundle,
    videoCallDetails: VideoNotification,
    notificationId: Int,
    channelId: String
): Notification? {
    val rejectIntent = Intent(applicationContext, IncomingCallNotificationService::class.java)
    rejectIntent.action = Constants.ACTION_REJECT
    rejectIntent.putExtra(Constants.VIDEO_CALL_DETAILS, videoCallDetails)
    rejectIntent.putExtra(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId)
    val piRejectIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        applicationContext,
        0,
        rejectIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    val acceptIntent = Intent(applicationContext, IncomingCallNotificationService::class.java)
    acceptIntent.action = ACTION_ACCEPT
    acceptIntent.putExtra(Constants.VIDEO_CALL_DETAILS, videoCallDetails)
    acceptIntent.putExtra(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId)
    val piAcceptIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        applicationContext,
        0,
        acceptIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call_end_white_24dp)
        .setContentTitle(INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL_TEXT)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_CALL)
        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
        .setExtras(extras)
        .setSound(soundUri)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete, getString(R.string.decline), piRejectIntent)
        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, getString(R.string.answer), piAcceptIntent)
        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
        .setTimeoutAfter(MomsezeApplication.notificationTimeOut)
    val notification = builder.build()
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT
    return notification
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun createChannel(channelImportance: Int): String? {
    var callInviteChannel = NotificationChannel(
        Constants.VOICE_CHANNEL_HIGH_IMPORTANCE,
        "Primary Voice Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    )
    var channelId = Constants.VOICE_CHANNEL_HIGH_IMPORTANCE
    if (channelImportance == NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW) {
        callInviteChannel = NotificationChannel(
            Constants.VOICE_CHANNEL_LOW_IMPORTANCE,
            "Primary Voice Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        channelId = Constants.VOICE_CHANNEL_LOW_IMPORTANCE
    }
    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
        .build()
    callInviteChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes)
    callInviteChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
    callInviteChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(callInviteChannel)
    return channelId
}

private fun handleIncomingCall(videoCallDetails: VideoNotification, notificationId: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setCallInProgressNotification(videoCallDetails, notificationId)
    }
    sendCallInviteToActivity(videoCallDetails, notificationId)
}

private fun endForeground() {
    stopForeground(true)
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun setCallInProgressNotification(
    videoCallDetails: VideoNotification,
    notificationId: Int
) {
    if (isAppVisible()) {
        startForeground(
            notificationId, createNotification(
                videoCallDetails,
                notificationId,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            )
        )
    } else {
        startForeground(
            notificationId, createNotification(
                videoCallDetails,
                notificationId,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
        )
    }
}

/*
 * Send the CallInvite to the VoiceActivity. Start the activity if it is not running already.
 */
private fun sendCallInviteToActivity(videoCallDetails: VideoNotification, notificationId: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29 && !isAppVisible()) {
        return
    }
    val intent = Intent(this, VideoActivity::class.java)
    intent.action = ACTION_INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ROOM_CODE, videoCallDetails.roomCode)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ROOM_NAME, videoCallDetails.roomName)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN, videoCallDetails.accessToken)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.CALLER_NAME, videoCallDetails.userName)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.CALL_RESPONSE_ACTION_KEY, Constants.INCOMING_CALL_SCREEN)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.CALL_TYPE, Constants.VIDEO_CALL)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL, true)
    intent.putExtra(Constants.NOTIFCATION_ID, notificationId)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    this.startActivity(intent)
}

private fun isAppVisible(): Boolean {
    return ProcessLifecycleOwner
        .get()
        .lifecycle
        .currentState
        .isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
}

private fun createRandomCode(codeLength: Int): Int {
    val chars = "1234567890".toCharArray()
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    val random: Random = SecureRandom()
    for (i in 0 until codeLength) {
        val c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.size)]
        sb.append(c)
    }
    return sb.toString().toInt()
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    isRunning = true
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
        broadCastReceiver, IntentFilter(
            Constants.NOTIFCATION_ID
        )
    )
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    isRunning = false
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver)
}

private val broadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        endForeground()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61646186/not-receiving-firebase-cloud-push-notifications-in-android-app/61679827#61679827

Answer (score 0):

You return `START_NOT_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`. When you swipe the app from the recent tasks list, Android kills the OS process hosting your app (and all the components `Activity`, `Service`, etc.). If you want Android to restart your `Service` automatically in this case, you need to return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: I think its not the service, the Firebase messaging service is what gets killed when app is closed or swiped from recent apps

Comment: Did you check https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Yes. Already have gone through it ! messages have only data payload, no notification added to message body. I think some of the Chinese ROM autokills the app when swiped or closed. Is there any workaround against this ?\

Comment: On some devices, notably low-end and Chinese manufacturers, you need to add your app manually to a list of "protected apps" or "apps that are allowed to run in the background". This is to help save battery life. Check in the settings on the phone, usually under "security" or "power management" or "battery". If there is such a list, you'll need to add your app manually to that list and tell your users to do it as well. There's no way to automatically or programmatically add your app to these lists.