# Android - In what way can I make notifications that will be updated every so often without kill the service?

Tags: android-studio, service, android-notifications, foreground

I wanted to know how to make a service like WhatsApp, the service won't die after 1 minute, it will display a notification that is updated every 12 hours or every 1 minute (the user chooses it in the app).

How can I make the service where the message can be rejected, and the service will not die but will display another notification after a while?

I tried to use `foreground`. Is it the right way? I'm not sure, because according to the `developers` site, the foreground must display notifications all the time. I don't want that.

What should I do? Thank you for any help

Comment: In my opinion you should use external program. Use cron task to run the code. You can run it every hour, check the conditions and then use FCM to wake up the device... See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61646186/not-receiving-firebase-cloud-push-notifications-in-android-app/61679827#61679827